# Compare string to multiple values gives always true

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to hide a Header component when I'm either on the login, register or confirmation page, but for some reason it only works properly when I give only one string to compare the path with.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Status from './auth/Status';

const Header = () => {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation()

  if (location.pathname === '/login') { return null }
  return (
    <nav className="bg-gray-800 p">
        // nav content
    </nav >
  )
};

export default Header;
```

This works fine on the login screen. The header is hidden and after you login, the header shows up again.

But when I try this:

```
if (location.pathname === '/login' || '/signup' || '/signup/confirm') { return null }
```

The header is disabled throughout the whole application.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition:

```
location.pathname === '/login' || '/signup' || '/signup/confirm'
```

...is interpreted as:

```
(location.pathname === '/login') || '/signup' || '/signup/confirm'
```

(See [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

...i.e. even if `location.pathname`is different from `'/login'`, the condition is truthy because the string `'/signup'` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Hence your Header is always disabled.

Properly build your condition, e.g. using [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (['/login', '/signup', '/signup/confirm'].includes(location.pathname)) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct condition would be:

```js
location.pathname === '/login' || location.pathname === '/signup' || location.pathname === '/signup/confirm'
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution also helped, but the way @ghybs has done it seems cleaner.